# Are $\text{Si}(1)$ , $\text{Ci}(1)$ and $\text{Ci}(1)-\gamma$ irrational numbers?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, irrational-numbers

The sine integral $\text{Si}(x)$ is defined as $$\text{Si}(x):=\int_0^x \frac{\sin(t)}{t}dt$$

and the cosine integral $\text{Ci}(x)$ is defined as $$\text{Ci}(x):=\gamma+\int_0^x \frac{\cos(t)-1}{t} dt+\ln(x)$$

$\gamma$ is the Euler-Macheroni-constant.

These functions are needed to calculate the following definite integrals :

$$\int_0^1 \ln(x)\cos(x) dx=-\text{Si}(1)$$

$$\int_0^1 \ln(x)\sin(x) dx=\text{Ci}(1)-\gamma$$

> Is it known, whether the numbers $\text{Si}(1)$ , $\text{Ci}(1)$ and $\text{Ci}(1)-\gamma$ are rational , irrational algebraic or transcendental ?

It is not known whether $\gamma$ is rational, but this does not rule out the possibility that the status of $\text{Ci}(1)-\gamma$ is known.

Comment: You can evaluate Si(1) by expanding the sine function in a Taylor series, and then maybe the irrationality proof for $e$ goes through.

Comment: Are you still here, Peter?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I will try to use your hint ...

Answer (score 0):

The following may help your quest,

Let:
$$H=\left(\sum_{n=1}^\inf\frac{\left(-1\right)^nx^{\left(2n\right)}}{\left(2n\right)!}\cdot\left(\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{i}\right)\right)$$
And:
$$I=\left(\sum_{n=0}^\inf\frac{\left(-1\right)^nx^{\left(2n+1\right)}}{\left(2n+1\right)!}\cdot\left(\sum_{i=1}^{2n+1}\frac{1}{i}\right)\right)$$
Then,
 compare u(x) to Si(x),

$$u(x) =-H\sin x+I\cos x$$
compare u'(x) to  the COCHLEOID.

Bet Regards: Escanellas.